# Camunda. Access to variable from delegate code

Tags: spring, camunda

Is it possible to somehow get the variables of the process in which it is currently running from the delegate's code (without forwarding a link to the DelegateExecution through a bunch of methods), or at least get the ProcessDefinitionId?

Something like

**@Autowired
CurrentDelegateExecution currentDelegateExecution**
or
**runtimeService.getCurrentProcess()**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding of how Camunda works, here. Such a thing as a "process in which it is currently running" does not exist, for any process model may be instantiated any number of times, creating multiple process instances.

You can however, query all active process instances using the runtimeService. From there on you may query variables or other specifics. For example:

```java
runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().active().list().stream()
            .map(processInstance -> runtimeService.getVariables(processInstance.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would leave you with a List of variable-maps.

Comment: I.e. processInstance in which it is currently running. Yes, this is how you can get a list of variables, but how to understand which ones relate to your instance running in this thread